# retrieve a declaration from service to displays it into component

Tags: angular, typescript

I want my likes counter to be handle in my post.service component, so I 've declared postLoveIts in the field of my class post.service component but I don't know how to retrieve it in my post-list.component and displays it in my the post-list.component template... thank you for your help !

**post.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Post } from '../models/post.model';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {
  
  postLoveIts : number = 0 ;

  private posts : Post[] = [
    {
          title: "Cuite mémorable avec mes friends",  
          content: "lorem ipsum",  
    }
  ];
  postsSubject = new Subject<any[]>();

  emitPosts() {
      this.postsSubject.next(this.posts);
    }

  
  createNewPost(newPost : Post) {
    this.posts.push(newPost);
    this.emitPosts();
  }

  removePost(post : Post) {
    const postIndexToRemove = this.posts.findIndex(
      (postEl) => {
        if(postEl === post) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return ' '
        }
      }
    );
    this.posts.splice(postIndexToRemove, 1);
    this.emitPosts();
  }



  addOne() {
    this.postLoveIts = this.postLoveIts + 1;
    console.log("like(s) :" + this.postLoveIts);
  }


  subtractOne() {
    this.postLoveIts = this.postLoveIts -1;
    console.log("like(s) :" + this.postLoveIts);
  }
```

**post-list.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Post } from '../models/post.model';
import { PostsService } from '../services/posts.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.scss']
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  

  posts : Post[];
  postsSubscription: Subscription;
  postLoveIts : number = 0 ;

  constructor(private postsService: PostsService,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postsSubscription = this.postsService.postsSubject.subscribe(
      (posts: Post[]) => {
        this.posts = posts;
      }
    );
    this.postsService.emitPosts()
  }

  onAddOne() {
    this.postsService.addOne();
  }


  onSubtractOne() {
    this.postsService.subtractOne()
  }

  onDeletePost(post: Post) {
    this.postsService.removePost(post);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.postsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**and post-list.component.html:**

```
      <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of posts">
                  <h3> {{ post.title }} </h3>
                  <p>  {{ post.content }} </p>
                  <p> {{ postLoveIts }} </p>   

                  <div class="container">
                        <button class="btn btn-success pull-left" (click)="onAddOne()"> J'aime </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger pull-left" (click)="onSubtractOne()"> J'aime pas </button>
                  
                  
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" 
                              (click)="onDeletePost(post)"> Supprimer </button>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Subject to emit changes of `postLoveIts` in your service and then subscribe to this Subject in your component, in the subscription you can simply update value of your `postLoveIts` field in the component.

Something like this (I skipped your code for the sake of readability but I'm assuming it's there):

```
export class PostsService {
  
  private postLoveIts$: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

  private emitUpdatedPostLoveIts(): void {
    this.postLoveIts$.next(this.postLoveIts);
  }

  watchPostLoveIts(): Observable<number> {
    return this.postLoveIts$.asObservable();
  }

  // below methods already exist in your code but I added one line to each of them
  addOne() {
    this.postLoveIts = this.postLoveIts + 1;
    console.log("like(s) :" + this.postLoveIts);
    emitUpdatedPostLoveIts(); // <- this is new line in this method
  }


  subtractOne() {
    this.postLoveIts = this.postLoveIts -1;
    console.log("like(s) :" + this.postLoveIts);
    emitUpdatedPostLoveIts(); // <- this is new line in this method
  }
}
```

and then just observe those changes of postLoveIts in the component:

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postsSubscription = this.postsService.postsSubject.subscribe(
      (posts: Post[]) => {
        this.posts = posts;
      }
    );
    this.postsService.emitPosts()

    this.postsService.watchPostLoveIts().subscribe(postLoveIts => {
      this.postLoveIts = postLoveIts;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you Pawel ! Do you have any idea on how can I bind this method on each post seperatly, because now it works fine but it's on the post list component. Do I have to create a single-post component in order to do that ? thank you for help

Comment: @GooshFen, you can add postLoveIts attribute to Post model so you would store it for each post separately. Then you just need some modifications: removing postLoveIts attribute from service and accept post object in addOne / subtractOne methods in service. `postLoveIts$` in service could be replaced with `updatedPosts$: Subject<Post>` and you could emit updated posts from it. So addOne/subtractOne would modify postLoveIts of post from parameter and then emit this post as updated one. In component you would need to find this post on this.posts list and update it.

Comment: ok thanks, I can try that but the thing is that post.model is more for user when he wants to create a new post so he will have the choice to add a like's number, haha... I'll see what I can do

Comment: @GooshFen, you don't have to give the possibility to modify it to the user. You have several options here, depending on how you initialize the post (how your forms look like) but generally you can simply initialize this model with postLoveIts set to zero by default (you can assign default value of zero in the model) and don't place any input or any other component which would modify it when user is creating a post. So the post can consist of a text and postLoveIts and the user would see input just for the text and modify only this one.